# Duplicate symbols error in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, mapbox

In my app, I was using FMDB till now. I want to use the MapBox framework, which also uses FMDB. When I add this framework to my project, I get the error "40 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7".

I read through the error and noticed that all the symbols duplicated are in FMDB.

Please suggest how can I use both FMDB(independently in my app) along with MapBox(which uses FMDB internally).

Comment: remove dependency on FMDB from before. MapBox will give you that access

Comment: Actually, the code that uses FMDB is scattered all over my project. If I remove the dependency then it given me a lot of errors. What I did as a leeway was that I manually "Find-And-Replace"ed the duplicates. Although this is not the correct way so I would still want to know what is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: There is not a correct way to do this aside from renaming or reworking to use the single copy. This is a limitation of Objective-C — no namespaces.

Comment: @incanus: Thank you. I had to rename a lot of things.